# Can you "clone" a java SecureRandom object? - How to get a cloneable strong RNG?

Tags: java, random, clone, entropy

**I have an application that needs long random bit sequences.**

Because I rely on these sequences being "truly random", I want to use SecureRandom.

**Sadly, I need each such sequence twice.**

**I cannot keep them in the RAM, because they're too long.**

I don't want to write them to the Hard Drive, because writing to and reading from the Hard Drive costs time and Hard Drive space and makes the code unnecessarily complex.

However, since the "random" bit sequence generated by some Generator deterministically depends on the state the Generator was in when it was created, one (maybe) may be able to save and recreate the state a newly generated SecureRandom object was in, allowing for **recreation of the bit sequence.**

The main question is:

**(How) Can you save the entire state of a SecureRandom random number generator? Is cloning enough? (there could be some OS states that also play a role, for example, the current time) Are there any other strong RNGs you can clone so that the original and the clone create the same output?**

Also, I'm interested in what sorts of patterns the normal Random number generators create, making them insecure, and whether one can save and recover their state as described above.

Edit:

I created a LCG for this purpose.

However, I think it does not work properly.

Does it create a "strong" pseudorandom bit sequence?

It got suspicious when it yielded the same value several times in a row.
For example:

false
false
true
true
true
true
false
true
false
false
false
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true

```
public class DeterministicRandom{
    private BigInteger state;
    private BigInteger a;
    private BigInteger c;
    private static final int o=32;
    private static final BigInteger m=BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(o*8);
    public DeterministicRandom(){
        a=RandomUtils.randomBigInt(o);
        c=RandomUtils.randomBigInt(o);
        state=RandomUtils.randomBigInt(o);
    }
    public DeterministicRandom(DeterministicRandom r){
        a=r.a;
        c=r.c;
        state=r.state;
    }
    public boolean nextBoolean(){
        boolean r=state.testBit(o*8-7);
        state=state.multiply(a).add(c).mod(m);
        return r;
    }
}
public class RandomUtils {
    private static Random random = new Random();
    public static byte[] nextBytes(byte[] d){
        random.nextBytes(d);
        return d;
    }
    public boolean randomBit(){
        return random.nextBoolean();
    }
    public static BigInteger randomBigInt(int bytes){
        byte[] d=new byte[bytes+1];
        random.nextBytes(d);
        d[0]=0;
        BigInteger x=new BigInteger(d);
        return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: One approach would be to use a `SecureRandom` to generate a seed, and then use that seed to create two regular `Random` instances.

Comment: Well, is Random "random" enough? Is Random "deterministic"? "Seed Generation: Random uses the system clock as the seed/or to generate the seed."-https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/random-vs-secure-random-numbers-java/ Do the answers to the above questions depend on the implementation? I really have to be shure that the sequence is regenerated exactly the way it was generated the first time.

Comment: `SecureRandom` generates a true random seed. If you use that to seed your two `Random` instances, they will produce identical pseudo-random deterministic sequences. If you want huge true random sequences, generating them will likely be slower than reading them from disk because collecting entropy data tends to be slow. All of the information you're requesting is in the JavaDoc and the specifications it refers to.

Comment: Well, another problem with Random might be that it may be not random enough, especially if you choose a bad seed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#Advantages_and_disadvantages so how can I get a deterministic and "recreatable" strong random number generator?

Comment: You can't have both. True randomness is diametrically opposed to determinism.

Comment: I don't want true random, but rather "strong random".

Comment: Can you explain what purpose you're generating random numbers for?  Is it for information security purposes (e.g., to generate encryption keys or to establish a secure connection)?  Or is it for a simulation, machine learning, a game, or something else?

Comment: Machine learning - a monte carlo method - very sensitive to bad PRNGs. How did you know? looking at the wikipedia article about the linear congruential generator it seems that this method creaates a strong random iff you choose large enough numbers and use the first bits. is that right?

Comment: What you want is called a pseudo-random number generator, and Java [already has one built in](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html). Unless you can mathematically show you need _better_ random number sequence generation, you don't need SecureRandom in the slightest. Just use Random, and only when you actually have proof that isn't good enough, start looking for a better PRNG.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/random-vs-secure-random-numbers-java/ : java Random uses 48 bits https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#Advantages_and_disadvantages : LCG for generating n random samples for monte carlo should have log2(n³) bits. -> the java LCG "holds" for creating about (2¹⁸ =) 262144 samples. thats very little samples. Therefore the build in random seems to be a bad option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can rely *in general* on a `SecureRandom` instance being cloneable, or on the clone providing the same sequence as the original.

The problem is that a typical Java platform provides multiple implementations of secure random, and when you call `new SecureRandom()` you get the default implementation.  This could be a PRNG or it could be a RNG that uses a source of "real" randomness.  In the latter case, even if `clone()` was supported by the class, the clone object wouldn't give the same random sequence as the original.

I can think of couple of solutions (in general).

---

The first solution is to create your own `Random` class that wraps a `SecureRandom` instance.  The special sauce is that your wrapper class needs to *record* the stream of random numbers that it hands out.  Then you need a `reset()` method that causes your PRNG to switch to using the recorded numbers.

The downside is that you need enough memory to hold all of the numbers.  (Depending on the representation, that could be a lot of memory.   For example if you record N integers in an `ArrayList<Integer>`, the worst case is N x 24 bytes for the `Integer` objects and a peak of 3 x N x 8 bytes for the `ArrayList`.  An `int[]` is much more dense, but more difficult to manage.)

I see that you have said that the sequences will be too long to hold in memory in your use-case.  You could consider writing them to a file, but even that doesn't scale indefinitely.

---

The second solution is to make use of the `SecureRandom` classes ability to select an algorithm and reseed itself.

```
SecureRandom seeder = new SecureRandom();
byte[] seed = seeder.generateSeed(NOS_BYTES);

SecureRandom prng = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
prng.setSeed(seed);

SecureRandom prng2 = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
prng2.setSeed(seed);

// prng1 and prng2 created as above should generate the same sequences
```

Set `NOS_BYTES` to the number of bytes of seed that you want to use.  Or you could generate a seed "by hand", or read it from a file.

Note that you cannot reliably set the seed like that on an instance you obtain using `new SecureRandom()`, and you cannot reliably re-seed an existing instance<sup>1</sup>.

There may be other PRNG algorithms that you could use, depending on your Java platforms configured Security Providers.

Please refer to the `SecureRandom` [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) for more information.

I tested the above approach and on my machine with Java 11, the `prng` and `prng2` objects generated the same sequence of `int` values ... until I hit ^C.

<sup>1 - The crux of the problem is that the javadoc for `setSeed` says this: *"The given seed supplements, rather than replaces, the existing seed."*.  Elsewhere, it says that the constructors return an object that has been seeded.  Fortunately, it also says that the `getInstance` methods return objects that have not been seeded.</sup>

---

Finally, I see from your updated question that you are considering using a "roll-your-own" PRNG implemented using `BigInteger`.

**Beware!**

It is very easy to implement a PRNG that is not as good as you think.  I wouldn't do that.  But if you decide to go down that route, you should read up on the theory of PRNGs and their properties and run a batch of (relevant) statistical tests on your implementation.

(And if you intend to publish your results, your paper should mention that you implemented your own PRNG, and you should make the PRNG source code and the statistical test results available for readers to check.  For the sake of openness and scientific reproducibility.   In my opinion.)

Comment: I tested your proposal using SecureRandom. on my device it worked perfectly fine too! Also, I really like the way you explain why this works, and that you point out several ways to address the problem this question deals with. Thank you very much for that!

Answer (score 3):

It seems you want random numbers for machine learning or Monte Carlo sampling. It also seems that you've also considered `java.util.Random` and found it unsuitable for your purposes. In that case, `SecureRandom` is far from being the best choice. In particular, there is no standard way to implement the "SHA1PRNG" provider of `SecureRandom`, and `SecureRandom` should not be used in cases when the application cares about reproducible "randomness". See also [Encryption algorithm giving different results on Android 2.1 and versions above 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358035/encryption-algorithm-giving-different-results-on-Android-2-1-and-versions-above).

Instead, you want a **high-quality PRNG**, and there are many [high-quality RNG algorithms](https://peteroupc.github.io/hqprng.html) available.

In Java, two [examples](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#Existing_RNG_APIs_in_Programming_Languages) include the `it.unimi.dsi/dsiutils` and `org.apache.commons/commons-rng-simple` artifacts, which include implementations of seedable PRNGs, such as `xoroshiro128++` and `xoshiro256**`.